# Accessing resource of a library referenced by a referenced project

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-resources, android-library

I have a test project X that tests project Y. Project Y has library Z as reference. library Z has a raw resource R1 which I'm trying to open but I keep getting resource not found. The raw resource is in res/raw folder within the library.

I tried openRawResource with the relevant packageManager but it did not seem to help.
Any idea? Is there any logical mistake in my resource allocation?

didn't work:

```
PackageManager pmMgr = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getPackageManager();
Resources rMgr = pmMgr.getResourcesForApplication("PROJECT.Y.PACKAGE");
InputStream is = rMgr.openRawResource(package.library.z.raw.R1);
```

neither did

```
PackageManager pmMgr = getInstrumentation().getContext().getPackageManager();
Resources rMgr = pmMgr.getResourcesForApplication("PROJECT.Y.PACKAGE");
InputStream is = rMgr.openRawResource(package.library.z.raw.R1);
```

P.S.
I verified that R1 is wrapped into the .apk of the referenced project (Y) under res/raw as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own questions.
Although only a day has passed since my question.. I've been struggling with this issue for a few days.

The solution is painfully stupid.
Newer versions of ADT require that you use the project library to call on resources even if they're from referenced libraries. E.g. to working code sample is:

```
PackageManager pmMgr = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getPackageManager();
Resources rMgr = pmMgr.getResourcesForApplication("PROJECT.Y.PACKAGE");
InputStream is = rMgr.openRawResource(package.library.Y.raw.R1);
```

the only change is in the last line, Y instead of Z.